# How to set stretch ratio in QtDesigner?

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qsplitter

I remember that I saw the property where I could set ratio values of elements widths enumerating them with comma.
There is a `QSplitter`. How can I set ratio of stretching it's widgets in QtDesigner?

Comment: Select the widget that has the layout and scroll to the bottom of the Property Editor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the stretch properties on the child widgets. Select one of the children, in the properties view look under **QWidget** for **sizePolicy** and expand it. Here you will find the **Horizontal Stretch** and **Vertical Stretch** properties.